# Arch Linux ARM audio not working (chromebook)

Tags: audio, chrome-book, arch-arm

I am currently booting Arch Linux ARM from an SD card on my Samsung Chromebook (model XE303C12). I have the XFCE4 DE installed with PulseAudio and Alsa-utils. I cannot get any audio to work what-so-ever on my installation. I've already tried unmuting using `alsamixer`, which didn't work. Can anyone help me fix my audio problem? Here is some extra info:

General system info:

```
[root@alarm alarm]# uname -a
Linux alarm 3.8.11-4-ARCH #1 SMP Sat Oct 22 11:59:55 MDT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Sound card info:

```
[root@alarm alarm]# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [DAISYI2S98090  ]: DAISY-I2S-98090 - DAISY-I2S-98090
                  DAISY-I2S-98090
```

Requested `journalctl` output:

```
[root@alarm alarm]# journalctl -xe
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit netctl@mlan0\x2dHoney1.service has begun starting up.
Aug 23 22:08:20 alarm network[556]: Starting network profile 'mlan0-Honey1'...
Aug 23 22:08:20 alarm kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): mlan0: link is not ready
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm kernel: mwifiex_sdio mmc2:0001:1: info: trying to associate        to 'Honey1' bssid 60:31:97:e0:97:1b
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm kernel: mwifiex_sdio mmc2:0001:1: info: associated to bssid 60:31:97:e0:97:1b successfully
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): mlan0: link becomes ready
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm systemd-networkd[155]: mlan0: Gained carrier
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm systemd[1]: Started Networking for netctl profile mlan0-Honey1.
-- Subject: Unit netctl@mlan0\x2dHoney1.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit netctl@mlan0\x2dHoney1.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm sudo[474]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm dhcpcd[683]: DUID 00:01:00:01:21:26:5f:84:fc:c2:de:31:2a:79
Aug 23 22:08:24 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: IAID de:31:2a:79
Aug 23 22:08:25 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.0.8
Aug 23 22:08:25 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: probing address 192.168.0.8/24
Aug 23 22:08:25 alarm systemd-networkd[155]: mlan0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 23 22:08:25 alarm systemd-timesyncd[197]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 23 22:08:30 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: leased 192.168.0.8 for 86400 seconds
Aug 23 22:08:30 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Aug 23 22:08:30 alarm systemd-timesyncd[197]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 23 22:08:30 alarm dhcpcd[683]: mlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Aug 23 22:08:31 alarm dhcpcd[683]: forked to background, child pid 732
Aug 23 22:08:31 alarm network[556]: Started network profile 'mlan0-Honey1'
Aug 23 22:09:02 alarm systemd-timesyncd[197]: Synchronized to time server 198.60.22.240:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 23 22:12:00 alarm su[831]: (to root) alarm on pts/0
Aug 23 22:12:00 alarm su[831]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
lines 2062-2094/2094 (END)
```

Comment: could you please search your `journalctl -xe` and look for something related with the speakers? Thanks

Comment: I executed the command specified, but all I could see was everything related to my wifi connection. I'm a little bit of a Linux newbie so I probably missed it. I edited in the output btw.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the audio codecs (the chips) used in Chromebooks are supported in recent kernel versions, some still aren't at all. You should check if there is a more recent kernel since 3.8 is very *very* old (this is the mayor downside of using ARM-based Chromebooks).

Workarounds include using Bluetooth A2DP or USB audio dongles/soundcards/DACs.

Comment: It seems that kernal 3.8 is the latest version available. Would a bluetooth headset / speaker work?

Comment: If your Bluetooth is working correctly then yes, it should work because it is not tied to the sound chip. The GalliumOS developers recommend it for the x86-based models where audio is currently not working and people like me use it that way, it shouldn't be any different on ARM. https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility